# Using HTML::Template within a value attribute

Tags: html, perl, templates

my question is how would I use an [HTML::Template](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/HTML::Template) tag inside a value of form field to change that field. For example

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="8" cellspacing="1">
        <tr> 
          <td align="right">File:</td> 
          <td>
        <input type="file" name="upload" value= style="width:400px">
          </td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr> 
          <td align="right">File Name:</td> 
          <td> 
            <input type="text" name="filename" style="width:400px" value=""  > 
          </td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr> 
          <td align="right">Title:</td> 
          <td> 
            <input type="text" name="title" style="width:400px" value="" /> 
          </td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr> 
          <td align="right">Date:</td> 
          <td> 
            <input type="text" name="date" style="width:400px" value="" /> 
          </td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr> 
         <td colspan="2" align="right"> 
           <input type="button" value="Cancel"> 
           <input type="submit" name="action" value="Upload" /> 
         </td> 
        </tr> 
      </table>
```

I want the value to have a `<TMPL_VAR>` variable in it.

Comment: You should be able to trim your post significantly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use it the same way you'd use a template variable anywhere else:

```
<input type="text" name="date" style="width:400px" value="<TMPL_VAR NAME=date>" />
```

Yeah, it's ugly and it breaks your HTML validator. Which is one of the many reasons why I like Template Toolkit better.

Comment: Beauty is in the eye of the beholder. Feeding XHTML to an HTML validator will not produce beautiful results either. And, in this particular case, why would there be any validation issue?